# Need c# to populate a number of records of a class in code

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and this code does not compile. I am trying to populate the List.
The syntax of the three record values contains squiggly lines. Can you please help me?  Thanks...John

```
private class Divisions {
   protected int uidDvsn { get; set; }
   protected string nameDvsn { get; set; }
}
private List<Divisions> divisions = {{1, "AL"}, { 2, "KEN" }, { 3, "FLA" }};
```

Comment: C# does not have such class initializer ({1, "AL"}) only for dictionary key-value. {new Divisions{uidDvsn =1, nameDvsn = "AL"}} will be valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do it, by using the following instruction:

```
private List<Divisions> divisions = new List<Divisions>() {
     new Divisions() { uidDvsn = 1, nameDvsn = "AL" },
     new Divisions() { uidDvsn = 2, nameDvsn = "KEN" }
};
```

Comment: This won't work until the properties are set to `public` instead of `protected`.

Comment: Yes, that's true, he should make them public or set getter and setter for each property.

Comment: Excellent ANSWER both with the "New Divisions" construct and also the change to PUBLIC.  You guys are GREAT!!!  thanks...John D.